Usage of word visión
Consider this translation,
English: There was a beautiful view of the river.
Spanish: Había una hermosa vista del río.
Would it be possible to use "visión" in a similar context as "vista"?
Something like "visión del río"?  Or that is never allowed...  Can you propose a sentence that uses "visión" to mean view such as view of a landscape?
I believe "visión" can mean view but in a more abstract way.

You cannot use "visión" as synonymous with "vista" to mean "view", but you can if you want to refer to the sense of sight.
"Su vista / visión es excelente" (he has a sharp sight)
"Visión" can be used to mean "view" in a more abstract, mental sense:

Mi visión de la vida es diferente (My view of life is different)

